# Problema en el get de mascota

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente código

```cs
public List<Mascota> getMascota()
        {
            List<Mascota> lista = new List<Mascota>();
            string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BDLocal"].ToString();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "Mascota_All";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    int id = dr.GetInt32(0);
                    string nombre = dr.GetString(1).Trim();
                    int edad = dr.GetInt32(2);
                    string desc = dr.GetString(3).Trim();

                    Mascota mascota = new Mascota(id, nombre, edad, desc);

                    lista.Add(mascota);
                }

                dr.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }

            return lista;
        }
```

El error lo tengo en Mascota mascota = new Mascota(id, nombre, edad, desc);

Me sale

bash
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   CS1503  Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'int' a 'string'  back_mascota    C:\Users\User\Downloads\crud-angular-asp-net-master\back_mascota\Models\GestorMascota.cs    36  Activo
me sale Gravedad   Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   CS1503  Argumento 2: no se puede convertir de 'int' a 'string'  back_mascota    C:\Users\User\Downloads\crud-angular-asp-net-master\back_mascota\Models\GestorMascota.cs    36  Activo
me sale Gravedad   Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   CS1503  Argumento 3: no se puede convertir de 'int' a 'string'  back_mascota    C:\Users\User\Downloads\crud-angular-asp-net-master\back_mascota\Models\GestorMascota.cs    36  Activo
me sale Gravedad   Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   CS1503  Argumento 4: no se puede convertir de 'int' a 'string'  back_mascota    C:\Users\User\Downloads\crud-angular-asp-net-master\back_mascota\Models\GestorMascota.cs    36  Activo

```
namespace back_mascota.Models
{
    public class Mascota
    {
        public int idMascota { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public int edad { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public int idTipo { get; set; }


        public Mascota() { }

        public Mascota(int id, string Nombre, int Edad, string desc, int tipo)
        {
            idMascota = id;
            nombre = Nombre;
            edad = Edad;
            descripcion = desc;
            idTipo = tipo;
        }

        public Mascota(string Nombre, int Edad, string desc, int tipo)
        {
            nombre = Nombre;
            edad = Edad;
            descripcion = desc;
            idTipo = tipo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de la clase `Mascota`?. Puedes hacer click en [edit] para editar tu pregunta

Comment: Si te fijas, el numero de parametros que envias no concuerda con el numero de parametros que tienes en tu primer constructor, que es de 5, estas enviando 4 parametros, esta tratando de utilizar tu segundo constructor que recibe 4 parametros y como por casualidad tienen orden inverso al ripo de dato que le envias, pues no los puede convertir, o agregas el ultimo parametro que es un `int tipo` cuando haces tu  `new Mascota(id, nombre, edad, desc, 1)` o haces opcional ese parametro en el constructor

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate, tú estás creando una mascota:

```
int id = dr.GetInt32(0);
string nombre = dr.GetString(1).Trim();
int edad = dr.GetInt32(2);
string desc = dr.GetString(3).Trim();
    
Mascota mascota = new Mascota(id, nombre, edad, desc);
```

Sin embargo, en tu clase tienes dos constructores :

```
Mascota(int id, string Nombre, int Edad, string desc, int tipo) 
Mascota(string Nombre, int Edad, string desc, int tipo)
```

Como a la hora de crear la mascota estás pasando 4 argumentos, se usa el siguiente:

```
Mascota(string Nombre, int Edad, string desc, int tipo)
```

En este caso, el primero de los parametros es un `string Nombre`, sin embargo, el valor que tú le estás pasando es un `int Id`.

Si lo que quieres es usar el primer constructor

```
Mascota(int id, string Nombre, int Edad, string desc, int tipo)
```

Tendrás que pasarle un parametro más que sea el `int tipo`